# Getting type from class

Tags: json, scala, reflection

I've been working on a project that stores case classes in a database and can take them back out again, storing them works fine but I am having trouble with getting them back out.

For items like Strings, Ints, Floats, etc, are being stored as they are but other types are converted to a JSON string using `json4s` like so

```
  private def convertToString(obj: AnyRef, objType: Class[_]): String = {
    implicit val formats = Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints)

    objType match {
      case t if t == classOf[String]      => obj.asInstanceOf[String]
      case t if t == classOf[Int]         => obj.toString
      case t if t == classOf[Integer]     => obj.toString
      case t if t == classOf[Boolean]     => if (obj.asInstanceOf[Boolean]) "true" else "false"
      case t if t == classOf[Short]       => obj.toString
      case t if t == classOf[Double]      => obj.toString
      case t if t == classOf[Long]        => obj.toString
      case t if t == classOf[Float]       => obj.toString
      case t if t == classOf[Byte]        => obj.toString
      case _                              => write(obj)(formats)
    }
  }
```

This is working fine and store items just like I would expect it to, but the problem is converting the items back from JSON.

Lets say I have the case class `Test(testInt: Int, testString: String, testMap: Map[String, _])` and I get the data back as `3,'blablabla','{"Test": "Map"}'`

I can put all values into a new instance of the class expect for the map, here is the code I am using

```
private def restoreTypes(objClass: Class[_], argList: Array[Object]): Array[_ <: Object] = {
    var correctTypes = Array.empty[Object]
    val fields = objClass.getDeclaredFields

    for(i <- 0 until fields.length) {
      val giveType = argList(i).getClass
      val wantedType = fields(i).getType

      if(giveType != wantedType && giveType == classOf[String])
        read[/*HERE*/](argList(i).asInstanceOf[String])
      else
        correctTypes = correctTypes :+ argList(i)
    }

    correctTypes
}
```

And this method is called list so

```
objClass.getConstructors()(0).newInstance(restoreTypes(objClass, args): _*)
```

I am getting stuck on how to pass the wanted type to the `read` method

Comment: I don't think is going to be a tractable approach, but I could be wrong. Why not just serialize, write to DB and deserialize when reading from DB (all using json4s or whatever)?

Comment: This is part of a library for CrateDB called crate-connector (https://github.com/HiveMedia/crate-connector), I am attempting to fix up the serialization and deserialization without going the easy way out and just converting the whole class to JSON. If it was a K/V database, the I would do that but with this DB I would prefer not to

Comment: oh I didn't realize you were trying to avoid the easy way. If you're going for the hard way, maybe you should write your program on tape and use a 1930's turing machine.

Comment: The comment wasn't meant to be an offensive just or anything, just trying to say that the library is designed for a SQL based database not a Key/Value database and whilst it would be easier to use a K/V and dump the whole json in that is not really the best way with SQL (for cross-platform ease)